# Flir Duo - Thermal Image to Temperature Matrix Conversion

Tags: opencv3.0, tiff, temperature, libtiff, flir

I am not sure if it is the right forum to ask questions regarding Flir Duo but I couldn't find a better place to ask the question.

Currently, I am using a Flir Duo along with BlackMagic Decklink and OpenCV. When I print the captured frame it prints a matrix of size width * height * depth (which is 3 -R, G, B). However, as per Flir manual I should get a **pixel value** to measure the temperature at a particular point. Can anyone suggest how to convert the RGB value to temperature value? If RGB format is incorrect (lost the information of TIFF), what will actual value look like? I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

Thank You